# Deluge not connecting to trackers sometimes.

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

Not really sure how to diagnose this problem. I'm using deluge running on a seedbox (I guess they call it), and deluge gui on a laptop. A torrent has been added to deluge that doesn't seem to be able to connect to any of the 4 trackers.

How can I find if an error message? This is all it's telling me in the gui:

```
Tracker Status: openbittorrent.com: Error:
```

This has happened to other torrents before. I'd like to know what's causing it. Editing the order of the trackers doesn't seem to be helping.

Comment: Your username contains an objectionable word.

Comment: you have a problem with the name lee or is it my last name?

Comment: Oh, so it's *lee*, not *leet*? Okay then. My bad.

Comment: It's all about perception I guess.